# Il termine "agata" può significare qualcosa fatta con l'ago?

Tags: word-meaning, grammar, orthography, homograph

Nel romanzo *Il sarto della stradalunga*, di Giuseppe Bonaviri, ho letto:

> Sino allora non sappiamo se il mondo esterno esiste, ma quando ci sediamo per rifinire a furia d'**agate** le maniche dei vestiti e le cinghie dei calzoni, ci meraviglia il silenzio che ci attornia.

La frase fa riferimento al lavoro di due sarti.

La mia domanda è sul termine "agata" che appare in questa frase: può significare il movimento dell'ago o qualcosa fatta con l'ago? Non ho trovato questa accezione (o qualcosa di simile) in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato.

Comment: È un po' come “petaloso”: l'italiano ha molti suffissi fertili, che permettono a chiunque di creare una parola sul momento. Se schiacci una zanzara con un giornale, puoi benissimo dire (colloquialmente, informalmente) che le hai dato una “giornalata” e nessuno si turberà.

Comment: Agàte potrebbe essere sostituita da "colpi d'ago"

Comment: @abarisone: Ho cercato l'espressione che hai proposto e ho trovato [questo](https://books.google.es/books?id=RGMVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=%22colpo+d%27ago%22+agata&source=bl&ots=KuDJyss3z2&sig=COxElu352V7ThJyEnaW3flHzqZ8&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5uL2Q-Z3bAhXBQ8AKHZSNA3wQ6AEIDjAB#v=onepage&q=%22colpo%20d'ago%22%20agata&f=false).

Comment: Il padre di Bonaviri era sarto: forse era un termine che usava lui.

Comment: @Charo Interessante, soprattutto la lista di parole che cambiano significato con il cambiare della posizione dell'accento. Magari raggruppo i vari contributi e provo a scrivere una risposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [agàta](https://books.google.es/books?id=RGMVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=%22colpo%20d%27ago%22%20agata&source=bl&ots=KuDJyss3z2&sig=COxElu352V7ThJyEnaW3flHzqZ8&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5uL2Q-Z3bAhXBQ8AKHZSNA3wQ6AEIDjAB#v=onepage&q=%22colpo%20d'ago%22%20agata&f=false) nel passaggio da te citato (che indica il lavoro di due sarti) si intende un colpo d'ago.

Come puntualmente sottolineato da @DaG, ci sono in Italiano un sacco di possibilità per creare parole alla bisogna, trasformando termini che rappresentano un oggetto in altri che descrivono l'azione portata a compimento con esso.

L'esempio di @DaG è particolarmente calzante riguardo al fatto che se schiaccio una zanzara con il giornale posso dire, in maniera informale:

> Ho eliminato quella zanzara fastidiosa con una bella giornalata.

Pensa anche ad esempio al fatto di andare a fare un giro in bicicletta che puoi esprimere come:

> Andiamo a fare una bella pedalata

Ovviamente in questo caso il termine [pedalata](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pedalata/) viene riportato dai dizionari, ma il senso è simile.

Ritornando al termine agàta è molto interessante notare che molte parole della lingua italiana sono "[omografe](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/omografi_(La-grammatica-italiana)/)", cioè sono parole che cambiano significato, come ad esempio in questo caso, con il cambiare della posizione dell'accento.

> Gli omografi (dal greco *omògraphos* ‘dalla grafia uguale’) sono parole
>   che hanno la stessa grafia, ma differiscono nella pronuncia.
>
> La diversa pronuncia può dipendere:
>
> – dalla diversa posizione dell’accento
>
> **àmbito** (sostantivo) / **ambìto** (participio passato del verbo ambire)
>
> **viòla** (sostantivo) / **vìola** (3a persona singolare dell’indicativo
>   presente del verbo violare)
>
> – oppure dal diverso grado di apertura della vocale accentata
>
> **pèsca** (= il frutto) / **pésca** (= azione del pescare)
>
> **pòrci** (= maiali) / **pórci** (= porre noi stessi).

Capita spesso che nei testi non venga riportato l'accento a meno che esso non cada sull'ultima sillaba e ciò può comportare difficoltà per il lettore, specie se non madrelingua.